# give alert after load lazy

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using [lazySizes jquery plugin](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes) and I want to have alert when my lazy loaded how can I do for my all loaded content ? I want to do this for my ajax content if I have alert I guess I can handle what I want to do

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.teaser.lazyload {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.8);
}
.teaser.lazyloaded {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 700ms;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="teaser lazyload" data-expand="-120">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum eum velit cumque, sint perspiciatis, ea nam illo repellat labore voluptates, vero inventore dolor fuga ipsum vel quas? Debitis, laborum eveniet?</p>
  <h1>Teaser Title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel excepturi saepe obcaecati repellat natus at enim fugit sapiente qui et corporis laudantium totam adipisci nihil, cumque rem reprehenderit aspernatur nostrum sunt voluptates tempora pariatur
    ea! Commodi quo minima similique quaerat velit vitae esse beatae quos illo dolores? Saepe quam, sed praesentium ut, vel quaerat, cupiditate laudantium expedita quisquam aperiam voluptatem quae illo cumque odit molestiae iure beatae odio? Omnis velit
    minima aspernatur qui voluptatum sapiente laudantium explicabo reiciendis architecto quaerat adipisci aliquam magni, reprehenderit iure fugit ex voluptas provident accusamus optio nostrum nemo sed soluta. Numquam quia, veniam molestias? Accusantium.</p>
</div>

<div class="teaser lazyload" data-expand="-120">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum eum velit cumque, sint perspiciatis, ea nam illo repellat labore voluptates, vero inventore dolor fuga ipsum vel quas? Debitis, laborum eveniet?</p>
  <h1>Teaser Title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel excepturi saepe obcaecati repellat natus at enim fugit sapiente qui et corporis laudantium totam adipisci nihil, cumque rem reprehenderit aspernatur nostrum sunt voluptates tempora pariatur
    ea! Commodi quo minima similique quaerat velit vitae esse beatae quos illo dolores? Saepe quam, sed praesentium ut, vel quaerat, cupiditate laudantium expedita quisquam aperiam voluptatem quae illo cumque odit molestiae iure beatae odio? Omnis velit
    minima aspernatur qui voluptatum sapiente laudantium explicabo reiciendis architecto quaerat adipisci aliquam magni, reprehenderit iure fugit ex voluptas provident accusamus optio nostrum nemo sed soluta. Numquam quia, veniam molestias? Accusantium.</p>
</div>


<div class="teaser lazyload" data-expand="-120">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum eum velit cumque, sint perspiciatis, ea nam illo repellat labore voluptates, vero inventore dolor fuga ipsum vel quas? Debitis, laborum eveniet?</p>
  <h1>Teaser Title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel excepturi saepe obcaecati repellat natus at enim fugit sapiente qui et corporis laudantium totam adipisci nihil, cumque rem reprehenderit aspernatur nostrum sunt voluptates tempora pariatur
    ea! Commodi quo minima similique quaerat velit vitae esse beatae quos illo dolores? Saepe quam, sed praesentium ut, vel quaerat, cupiditate laudantium expedita quisquam aperiam voluptatem quae illo cumque odit molestiae iure beatae odio? Omnis velit
    minima aspernatur qui voluptatum sapiente laudantium explicabo reiciendis architecto quaerat adipisci aliquam magni, reprehenderit iure fugit ex voluptas provident accusamus optio nostrum nemo sed soluta. Numquam quia, veniam molestias? Accusantium.</p>
</div>


<div class="teaser lazyload" data-expand="-220">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum eum velit cumque, sint perspiciatis, ea nam illo repellat labore voluptates, vero inventore dolor fuga ipsum vel quas? Debitis, laborum eveniet?</p>
  <h1>Teaser Title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel excepturi saepe obcaecati repellat natus at enim fugit sapiente qui et corporis laudantium totam adipisci nihil, cumque rem reprehenderit aspernatur nostrum sunt voluptates tempora pariatur
    ea! Commodi quo minima similique quaerat velit vitae esse beatae quos illo dolores? Saepe quam, sed praesentium ut, vel quaerat, cupiditate laudantium expedita quisquam aperiam voluptatem quae illo cumque odit molestiae iure beatae odio? Omnis velit
    minima aspernatur qui voluptatum sapiente laudantium explicabo reiciendis architecto quaerat adipisci aliquam magni, reprehenderit iure fugit ex voluptas provident accusamus optio nostrum nemo sed soluta. Numquam quia, veniam molestias? Accusantium.</p>
</div>


<div class="teaser lazyload" data-expand="-220">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum eum velit cumque, sint perspiciatis, ea nam illo repellat labore voluptates, vero inventore dolor fuga ipsum vel quas? Debitis, laborum eveniet?</p>
  <h1>Teaser Title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel excepturi saepe obcaecati repellat natus at enim fugit sapiente qui et corporis laudantium totam adipisci nihil, cumque rem reprehenderit aspernatur nostrum sunt voluptates tempora pariatur
    ea! Commodi quo minima similique quaerat velit vitae esse beatae quos illo dolores? Saepe quam, sed praesentium ut, vel quaerat, cupiditate laudantium expedita quisquam aperiam voluptatem quae illo cumque odit molestiae iure beatae odio? Omnis velit
    minima aspernatur qui voluptatum sapiente laudantium explicabo reiciendis architecto quaerat adipisci aliquam magni, reprehenderit iure fugit ex voluptas provident accusamus optio nostrum nemo sed soluta. Numquam quia, veniam molestias? Accusantium.</p>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lazysizes/2.0.7/lazysizes.min.js"></script>
```

[click to see codepen](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/MJZzQb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin does not document this very well, but there are several events being fired by it, namely `lazybeforeunveil`, `lazybeforesizes` and `lazyunveilread`. I'm not sure about their exact order, but you can bind to `lazyunveilread` in order to achieve what you want:

```js
$('.teaser.lazyload').on('lazyunveilread', function(ev) {
  alert("foo!");
  console.log(ev.target); // <-- that's how you can get the element that has been loaded
});
```

```css
@import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css";
  
  body{
  padding:30px;
  width:80%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.teaser.lazyload {
 opacity: 0;
 transform: scale(0.8);
}

.teaser.lazyloaded {
 opacity: 1;
 transform: scale(1);
 transition: all 700ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lazysizes/2.0.7/lazysizes.min.js"></script>
<div class="teaser lazyload" data-expand="-120">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum eum velit cumque, sint perspiciatis, ea nam illo repellat labore voluptates, vero inventore dolor fuga ipsum vel quas? Debitis, laborum eveniet?</p>
    <h1>Teaser Title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel excepturi saepe obcaecati repellat natus at enim fugit sapiente qui et corporis laudantium totam adipisci nihil, cumque rem reprehenderit aspernatur nostrum sunt voluptates tempora pariatur ea! Commodi quo minima similique quaerat velit vitae esse beatae quos illo dolores? Saepe quam, sed praesentium ut, vel quaerat, cupiditate laudantium expedita quisquam aperiam voluptatem quae illo cumque odit molestiae iure beatae odio? Omnis velit minima aspernatur qui voluptatum sapiente laudantium explicabo reiciendis architecto quaerat adipisci aliquam magni, reprehenderit iure fugit ex voluptas provident accusamus optio nostrum nemo sed soluta. Numquam quia, veniam molestias? Accusantium.</p>
</div>

<div class="teaser lazyload" data-expand="-120">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum eum velit cumque, sint perspiciatis, ea nam illo repellat labore voluptates, vero inventore dolor fuga ipsum vel quas? Debitis, laborum eveniet?</p>
    <h1>Teaser Title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel excepturi saepe obcaecati repellat natus at enim fugit sapiente qui et corporis laudantium totam adipisci nihil, cumque rem reprehenderit aspernatur nostrum sunt voluptates tempora pariatur ea! Commodi quo minima similique quaerat velit vitae esse beatae quos illo dolores? Saepe quam, sed praesentium ut, vel quaerat, cupiditate laudantium expedita quisquam aperiam voluptatem quae illo cumque odit molestiae iure beatae odio? Omnis velit minima aspernatur qui voluptatum sapiente laudantium explicabo reiciendis architecto quaerat adipisci aliquam magni, reprehenderit iure fugit ex voluptas provident accusamus optio nostrum nemo sed soluta. Numquam quia, veniam molestias? Accusantium.</p>
</div>


<div class="teaser lazyload" data-expand="-120">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum eum velit cumque, sint perspiciatis, ea nam illo repellat labore voluptates, vero inventore dolor fuga ipsum vel quas? Debitis, laborum eveniet?</p>
    <h1>Teaser Title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel excepturi saepe obcaecati repellat natus at enim fugit sapiente qui et corporis laudantium totam adipisci nihil, cumque rem reprehenderit aspernatur nostrum sunt voluptates tempora pariatur ea! Commodi quo minima similique quaerat velit vitae esse beatae quos illo dolores? Saepe quam, sed praesentium ut, vel quaerat, cupiditate laudantium expedita quisquam aperiam voluptatem quae illo cumque odit molestiae iure beatae odio? Omnis velit minima aspernatur qui voluptatum sapiente laudantium explicabo reiciendis architecto quaerat adipisci aliquam magni, reprehenderit iure fugit ex voluptas provident accusamus optio nostrum nemo sed soluta. Numquam quia, veniam molestias? Accusantium.</p>
</div>


<div class="teaser lazyload" data-expand="-220">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum eum velit cumque, sint perspiciatis, ea nam illo repellat labore voluptates, vero inventore dolor fuga ipsum vel quas? Debitis, laborum eveniet?</p>
    <h1>Teaser Title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel excepturi saepe obcaecati repellat natus at enim fugit sapiente qui et corporis laudantium totam adipisci nihil, cumque rem reprehenderit aspernatur nostrum sunt voluptates tempora pariatur ea! Commodi quo minima similique quaerat velit vitae esse beatae quos illo dolores? Saepe quam, sed praesentium ut, vel quaerat, cupiditate laudantium expedita quisquam aperiam voluptatem quae illo cumque odit molestiae iure beatae odio? Omnis velit minima aspernatur qui voluptatum sapiente laudantium explicabo reiciendis architecto quaerat adipisci aliquam magni, reprehenderit iure fugit ex voluptas provident accusamus optio nostrum nemo sed soluta. Numquam quia, veniam molestias? Accusantium.</p>
</div>


<div class="teaser lazyload" data-expand="-220">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum eum velit cumque, sint perspiciatis, ea nam illo repellat labore voluptates, vero inventore dolor fuga ipsum vel quas? Debitis, laborum eveniet?</p>
    <h1>Teaser Title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel excepturi saepe obcaecati repellat natus at enim fugit sapiente qui et corporis laudantium totam adipisci nihil, cumque rem reprehenderit aspernatur nostrum sunt voluptates tempora pariatur ea! Commodi quo minima similique quaerat velit vitae esse beatae quos illo dolores? Saepe quam, sed praesentium ut, vel quaerat, cupiditate laudantium expedita quisquam aperiam voluptatem quae illo cumque odit molestiae iure beatae odio? Omnis velit minima aspernatur qui voluptatum sapiente laudantium explicabo reiciendis architecto quaerat adipisci aliquam magni, reprehenderit iure fugit ex voluptas provident accusamus optio nostrum nemo sed soluta. Numquam quia, veniam molestias? Accusantium.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: hi it's great example but is there any way to just has only lazy_content class..I mean do just `lazy_content` class

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use jQuery "scroll()" to check if the page is scrolled fully down since as far as I know lazyloading works when we scroll the page so you need to capture that you are at the bottom of the page to show an alert.

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
    alert("Bottom Of the Page");
  }
});
```

Comment: The OP states "how can I do for my all loaded content" - so I don't think he's looking for that kind of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Lazysizes doesnt have any explicit event handler to know when the lazyload is done. you don't need it too. 
In general all you need is `lazybeforeunveil` to modify the transformation or load to be informed when the image is loaded.

In some specific circumstances you could use setImmediate/setTimeout inside a lazybeforeunveil.

```
$(document).on('lazybeforeunveil', function(){
    //do your stuff.. (setTimeout if required)
});
```

It is quite consistent. hope it helps